# SWIFT: Modal Segue From TableViewCell (Prototype Cell) Is Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I dragged a TableViewCell to a new view controller to create a Modal segue. It worked perfectly, and then all of a sudden it stopped. I have not added any Swift code for the segue as yet...I'm racking my brain as to why this has happened out of the blue.  I've looked at all of the other posts, but none of the solutions are working.  What could be the possible causes?

Comment: "All of a sudden it stopped"? Any errors or unexpected behaviour? Cannot help without seeing some code / additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing and adding the segue, or check in the cell the *Enable user interaction* to be `true`

Comment: @dGamit, thank you!  This was actually a major oversight on my part.  Once I checked "User Interaction Enabled" on the Table View Cell, it worked